# Apple Guideline - Strange rule for publishing app

Tags: ios, publish, appstore-approval

I work in a App Development company, we've developed and designed an app entirely from scratch, published with our own enterprise account, but Apple reject based on a strange rule:

> "Guideline 4.2.6 - Design - Commercialized Templates and App Generation Services
>
> Apps created from a commercialized template or app generation service will be rejected unless they are submitted directly by the provider of the app’s content. These services should not submit apps on behalf of their clients and should offer tools that let their clients create customized, innovative apps that provide unique customer experiences. Another acceptable option for template providers is to create a single binary to host all client content in an aggregated or “picker” model, for example as a restaurant finder app with separate customized entries or pages for each client restaurant, or as an event app with separate entries for each client event."

We're not using any template on app and we are not a mass-app generation company. How can they say we've using templates?

Has anyone have similar problem and can help me with that?

Comment: You will need to resolve this directly with Apple; You can lodge an appeal and ask them why they think your app uses a template.  Also, there may be a mismatch between the branding/content of the app and the name of your company that is causing them to reject the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the rejection message is rather generic the main point is:

**You can no longer publish apps for 3rd parties under your own developer account.** (I assume that you meant [organization developer account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/), because [enterprise developer accounts](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) cannot publish on the public App Store)

So as an agency or developer, you can still develop the app for your customer. But once it's ready, **your customer will need his/her own developer account.** They can invite you to the account and you can upload the app for them. Apple is also pushing organization developer accounts, so it's also no longer possible to publish company apps under individual accounts, even if you work for that company.